# SESSION não está carregando as variáveis $_SESSION['']

Tags: php, session

Estou fazendo um sistema de autenticação de usuário baseado em SESSIONS. Criei uma função que faz o LOGOUT que está assim:

```
session_destroy(); // Cancela/Exclui a sessão iniciada

unset($_SESSION['usuario']);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

location.href='index.php';

</script>
```

Porém ao clicar no botão "voltar" do navegador, o script não está direcionando para a página inicial. Coloquei o seguinte código na página protegida:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
header("Location: index.php?error=2");
}
```

Na página de autenticação, meu código está assim:

```
$usuario= $row["usuario_id"];
$nivel = $row["nivel_usuario"];
$nome   = $row["nome"];
$fnc    = $row["funcao"];

    session_start();

    if($nivel == 2 ){


        $_SESSION['adm'] = "$nome";
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = "$usuario";

    } else {

        $_SESSION['nor'] = "$nome";
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = "$usuario";              

    }    

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "pages/index.php?fnc=' .  $fnc  . '"</script>';

}

} else {

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "index.php?erro=2"</script>';

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
session_destroy();   
session_unset();
```